# Where should project based media be stored?

Tags: azure-devops, repository

We use Azure DevOps to store our source and maintain a separate group of folders for images, documents, videos and other media. This arrangement has been fine for my in-house dev team, but we recently started using contractors. Packaging up a subset of our massive media library was easy enough, but I thought I'd see what the current thought is on storing project media.

I found this article, but the suggestions didn't look like a good fit for us.
https://opensource.com/article/19/4/manage-multimedia-files-git

Comment: Is this just for media storage, or do you want to have the media under source control because it changes?

Comment: It is added to and updated often

Comment: What about this?  https://github.com/alebedev/git-media

Comment: @Narthring Thanks - It looks similar to the solution I mentioned in my question, but I will check it out further.

Comment: I checked again and yeah, you're right.  I had thought that your original link was Git support for large media files, but I think I was confused on something else I was looking at.  I'm surprised at the low response too.  I'd expect this is a common problem.